# How do i remove only one trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This snippet will remove all the slashes on the end of a url

```
# Remove the trailing slash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but how do i customize this to only do it for

```
http://site.com/only_me/
```

to

```
http://site.com/only_me
```

Also do what is this doing

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site\.com$ [NC]
```

and do i need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `RewriteRule ^only_me\/$ http://site.com/only_me [R=301, L]`

Comment: do i need the RewriteCond also

Comment: Yes only change the RewriteRule below the RewriteCond. The RewriteCond basically checks the requested host. The rule is looking for a particular path. Edited the answer, you need to escape the /